# How to deploy image to kubernetes with jib and maven

Tags: maven, kubernetes, skaffold

I have environment where I can simply push images(created with Jib) to local repository. I want to now to be able to deploy this on kubernetes, but from the "safety" of maven.

I know I can spin some Skaffold magic, but I don't like to have it installed separately. Is there some Jib-Skaffold workflow I can use to continuously force Skaffold to redeploy on source change(without running it in command line)

Is there some Skaffold plugin? I really like what they have [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6gR_Cv4yWI&t=1219s), but proposed kubernetes-dev-maven-plugin is probably internal only.

Comment: Have you considered to use a CI server that performs the build and application update in kubernetes?

Comment: This is for local development. For other environment CI will be option, but not here.

Comment: Perhaps using telepresence would better fit your needs: https://www.telepresence.io/tutorials/java

Comment: It is nice concept, but I'd like to have the local dev environment similar to other environment we are using for testing or production. I also want to offload all heavy lifting to remote hardware. The Telepresence is cool project anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Skaffold can [monitor your local code and detect changes that will trigger a build and deployment](https://skaffold.dev/docs/workflows/dev/) in your cluster. This is built-in on Skaffold using the `dev` mode so it solves the *redeploy on source change* part.

As for the workflow, Jib is a [supported builder for Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/jib/) so the same dynamic applies.

Although these features automate the tasks, it is still necessary to run it once with `skaffold dev` and let it run in the "background".

Comment: I'm just missing some maven integration. I found [fabric8](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) maven plugin which have some "source watching" capability, but still I prefer to integrate Jib in the flow.